# Integrability and limit at infinity?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we have $\ \int_0^{\infty} e^{Rx} (1-F(x))dx < \infty$ where $F$ is the cdf of some nonnegative random variable $X$. When can we say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}e^{Rx} (1-F(x))=0$? 
I'm trying to integrate by parts and I need this limit to converge to $0$.

It's bothering me because I know from measure and Lebesgue integration theory that an integrable function doesn't necessarily vanish at infinity but it does if the function is uniformly continuous. I tried to suppose $X$ is a continuous rv to simplify matters but 
this assumption only tells me $F$ must consequently be uniformly continuous since it is bounded monotone, increasing and continuous which doesn't help.

The only thing I know is that if the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}e^{Rx} (1-F(x))$ exists then it must be $0$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ \int_0^\infty e^{Rx}(1-F(x))\,dx<\infty $, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $x_0$ such that if $ x>x_0 $ then
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon>\int_{x_0}^xe^{Ru}(1-F(u))\,du&\ge (1-F(x))\int_{x_0}^xe^{Ru}\,du\\
&=(1-F(x))\frac{e^{Rx}-e^{Rx_0}}{R}.
\end{align*}
Hence
$$ (1-F(x))e^{Rx}<R\varepsilon+(1-F(x))e^{Rx_0}, $$
and
$$ \limsup_{x\to\infty}(1-F(x))e^{Rx}\le R\varepsilon+ \limsup_{x\to\infty}(1-F(x))e^{Rx_0} =R\varepsilon.
$$
Due to the $ \varepsilon>0 $ is an arbitrary positive number, we could conclude that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}(1-F(x))e^{Rx}=0. $$

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to set a bounty a accept your answer to give more points.

Comment: @John11 You are welcome. I am very glad that you accept my answer.